Issue with External Review Email Sharing in Advanced CMS Add-on (Optimizely 11)
I have installed version 0.9.3 of the Advanced CMS - Add-on for Advanced & External Reviews on Optimizely 11. The problem I'm encountering is that the functionality to share external review emails is not working.The error says, sender email is missing.
Below is the additional code I've included besides the NuGet package.
 [InitializableModule]
    [ModuleDependency(typeof(FrameworkInitialization))]
    public class ExternalReviewInitialization : IConfigurableModule
    {
        public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            context.ConfigurationComplete += (o, e) =>
            {
                //Register custom implementations that should be used in favour of the default implementations
            };

            context.Services.Configure<ExternalReviewOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ContentPreviewUrl = "externalContentView";
                options.IsEnabled = true;
                options.IsReviewCommentsCommandEnabled = true;
                options.EditableLinksEnabled = true;
                options.PinCodeSecurity.Enabled = false;
                options.PinCodeSecurity.Required = false;
                options.PinCodeSecurity.CodeLength = 5;
                options.ProlongDays = 10;
               
            });


            context.Services.Configure<EPiServer.Notification.NotificationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.NotificationEmailAddress = "xyz@zyz.com";
            });
        }

        public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
        {
            

        }

        public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine context) { }
    }

After reviewing the open-source file
https://github.com/advanced-cms/advanced-reviews/blob/net4_master/src/external-reviews/ReviewLinksRepository/ExternalReviewStore.cs#L104, the error message indicates that the sender email is missing
Is there something that I am missing in terns of configuration.
Any input is appreciated.
